# Region of Practical Equivalence (ROPE)

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, epidemiology, credible-interval

I seek to understand how to employ the Region of Practical Equivalence (ROPE), so I conducted a basic Bayesian analysis of disease incidence rates on a public data set.

Is my rationale sound regarding the ROPE in my analysis?

I have reproduced my process below and would greatly appreciate any feedback. This post also appears [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/1bq8yc2/check_my_bayesian_analysis/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

#### Data Preparation

```
require(tidyverse)
require(rstanarm)

# Yearly counts for Hepatitis A, Measles, Mumps, Pertussis, Polio, Rubella, and 
# Smallpox for US states
infect <- read_csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/dslabs/us_contagious_diseases.csv")

# Reclassify as factor variables
infect$disease <- as.factor(infect$disease)
infect$state <- as.factor(infect$state)

# Calculate cases per 100000
infect$incidence <- (infect$count / infect$population) * 100000

# Subset and return only measles data
measles <- infect %>%
  filter(disease == "Measles") %>%
  select(-disease) # disease column no longer needed

# View incidence distribution for measles
measles %>%
  pull(incidence) %>% 
  hist(., main = "Distribution of Mean Incidence of Measles")

# Zoom into the lower end of the distribution
measles %>%
  filter(incidence <= 10) %>%
  pull(incidence) %>%
  hist(., main = "Distribution of Mean Incidence of Measles (<= 10")

# Mean incidence of measles by year
measles_year <- measles %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(mean_incidence = mean(incidence, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()

# Line plot using a GAM smoothing
# Plot a vertical line at vaccine year (1963)
measles_year %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = mean_incidence)) +
  geom_smooth(se = TRUE, method = "gam") + # GAM smoothed line with standard error region
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(measles_year$year),
                                  max(measles_year$year), by = 4)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1963, linetype = "dashed", color = "red", linewidth = 1) + # Adds a vertical line for 1963
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Annual Mean Incidence of Measles: United States",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Mean Incidence per 100,000") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) # Rotate x labels for readability
```

#### Set Up & Run a Bayesian Model

From the histograms, incidence rates for measles seem to follow a gamma distribution.

Set up a Bayesian model where:

1. The likelihood for the data (incidence rates) is gamma distributed
2. The priors for the regression coefficients are normally distributed

H0: There is no difference in the incidence rates before and after vaccination
HA: There is a difference in the incidence rates before and after vaccination

```
# Create a binary variable 'vaccine_status' to indicate pre- and post-vaccination periods
measles_year <- measles_year %>%
  mutate(vaccine_status = ifelse(year < 1963, "pre", "post")) %>% # Insert a column named `vaccine_status`
  mutate(vaccine_status = factor(vaccine_status, # reclassify as a factor variable
                                 levels = c("pre", "post"))) # reorder factor levels to ensure the first level is "pre"

# Reserve one core for the operating system.
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores() - 1)

# Fit a Bayesian regression model with gamma likelihood
bayesian_model <- stan_glm(mean_incidence ~ vaccine_status,
                           data = measles_year,
                           family = Gamma(link = "log"), # Using Gamma family with log link function
                           prior = normal(0, 2.5, autoscale = TRUE), # Weakly informative normal prior for coefficients
                           prior_intercept = normal(0, 10, autoscale = TRUE), # Weakly informative normal prior for intercept
                           algorithm = "sampling", # Use MCMC sampling
                           chains = 4,
                           iter = 2000,
                           seed = 123)

# Convert the Bayesian model object to a data frame:
posterior_samples <- as.data.frame(bayesian_model)

# Note: "pre" is the baseline group. Thus, the model coefficients represent the "post" group
# Extract the posterior distribution of the model coefficients:
vaccine_status_posterior <- posterior_samples[, "vaccine_statuspost"]

# As these model coefficients are on a log scale, exponentiate them, subtract
# them from 1, and multiply by 100 to represent the percent reduction in incidence
# rates from pre- to post vaccine years
reduction <- (1 - exp(vaccine_status_posterior)) * 100
                
# Calculate the 95% credible interval
ci <- quantile(reduction, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))

# Plot of posterior distribution with 95% credible interval:
ggplot(data.frame(reduction), aes(x = reduction)) +
  geom_density(fill = "skyblue", alpha = 0.5) +  # Plot density
  geom_vline(xintercept = ci, col = "red", linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 1) +  # Credible interval
  annotate("text", x = ci[1] - 2, y = -0.01, label = paste(round(ci[1], 2)), vjust = -1, color = "red") +
  annotate("text", x = ci[2] + 2, y = -0.01, label = paste(round(ci[2], 2)), vjust = -1, color = "red") +
  labs(title = "Posterior Distribution of Vaccine Effect", 
       x = "Percent Reduction In Incidence", y = "Density") +
  theme_minimal()
```

#### Set the Region of Practical Equivalence (ROPE)

Here's where my understanding gets murky.

Let's say the measles vaccination program was successful if we achieved at least a 50% reduction in the incidence rate. Our hypothesis:

H0: We did not achieve at least 50% reduction in incidence
HA: We did achieve at least 50% reduction in incidence

If we set the ROPE at [40%, 60%], this interval falls far outside the credible interval [85.05%, 96.01]. Thus, we can reject H0 and assert that we exceeded our expectations of reducing the incidence of measles.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Admittedly, my original post did not contain a direct question. I will clarify!